# Make async HTTP call on window close event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just want to logout on window close but due to async call it's not possible. Is there any way to do it without making a sync call?

`beforeunload` event is working fine with window refresh but not with window close.

Comment: As I understand you want to logout from server on window close. What if you just delete cookies instead of sending http-request?

Comment: Imagine you have several tabs opened: you can't rely on window.close.  If your application is only for 1 tab, imagine you have a power shutdown, or if you kill the web-browser process. You should either: use sessionStorage, which will be freed once you close the tab, or set a validity_date in the oauth connection, when it expires and if you open the window on the page, you disconnect.

Comment: Can you expand on the `beforeunload` event a little bit?

Comment: @AnthonyMayfield I am using 'beforeunload' to call the logout function(containing async call). Its working fine in the case of refresh but not in case of window close.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant  
I am using sessionStorage and I am clearing it at the time of logout but I also want to remove the entry from the database at the time of window close.

Comment: @AdityaKumawat: front-end: no problem, sessionStorage erased when tab closed. backend: you need to launch a command to remove all the expired tokens. Under SF2 with OAuthServerBundle: `php app/console fos:oauth-server:clean` and you put it in a cron one an hour.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Can u please give me the details how to do it?

Comment: @AdityaKumawat: To do 'what' ? Since you can't be sure the onclose event is fired in the client browser, you need to execute automatically one script n times an hour.  In this script you do your sql query to remove the expired tokens. And  for cron, read http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Thanx.....hope that might work.

Comment: @AdityaKumawat: if you don't do that, you will just accumulate expired tokens that weren't deleted because the client didn't send the "onclose" event.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant got it.....thanx.